# Ubuntu server not allowing shutdown

Tags: apt, server, mysql, shutdown, unattended-upgrades

I attempted to shut down my Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS server earlier today. On doing so, I got the following message:

```
Operation inhibited by "APT" (PID 729631 "unattended-upgr", user root), reason is "APT is installing or removing packages".
Please retry operation after closing inhibitors and logging out other users.
Alternatively, ignore inhibitors and users with 'systemctl poweroff -i'.
```

Similarly, this inhibits running apt, which I tried to see if that would help matters along:

```
Waiting for cache lock: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 729611 (unattended-upgr)..
```

I looked into what was causing this lock, and found the following processes have been running since this morning:

```
$ sudo ps -eaf | grep -i apt
root      729574       1  0 06:37 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh /usr/lib/apt/apt.systemd.daily install
root      729579  729574  0 06:37 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh /usr/lib/apt/apt.systemd.daily lock_is_held install
$ sudo ps -eaf | grep -i unat
root        1073       1  0 Nov20 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/share/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrade-shutdown --wait-for-signal
root      729611  729579  0 06:37 ?        00:02:06 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
root      729631  729611  0 06:37 ?        00:01:00 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
```

I've checked the progress of the upgrades, and this gave me a culprit and a progress indicator, which has not moved at all in the last 3 or 4 hours:

```
$ tail -f /var/run/unattended-upgrades.progress
Progress: 84.6154 % (mysql-server-8.0)
```

Here are the running mysql related processes:

```
$ ps -ef | grep mysql
root      729960  729959  0 06:40 pts/0    00:00:00 /usr/bin/perl -w /usr/share/debconf/frontend /var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-8.0.postinst configure 8.0.22-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
root      729966  729960  0 06:40 pts/0    00:00:00 /bin/bash /var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-8.0.postinst configure 8.0.22-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
root      730079  729966  0 06:42 pts/0    00:00:00 fuser /var/lib/mysql/ibdata1
```

and what seems like the log of the update that has hung:

```
$ cat /var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades-dpkg.log
Log started: 2020-12-01  06:37:25
Preconfiguring packages ...
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 139629 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-client-8.0_8.0.22-0ubuntu0.20.04.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-client-8.0 (8.0.22-0ubuntu0.20.04.3) over (8.0.22-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-8.0_8.0.22-0ubuntu0.20.04.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server-8.0 (8.0.22-0ubuntu0.20.04.3) over (8.0.22-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-core-8.0_8.0.22-0ubuntu0.20.04.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server-core-8.0 (8.0.22-0ubuntu0.20.04.3) over (8.0.22-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) ...
Setting up mysql-server-core-8.0 (8.0.22-0ubuntu0.20.04.3) ...
Setting up mysql-client-8.0 (8.0.22-0ubuntu0.20.04.3) ...
Setting up mysql-server-8.0 (8.0.22-0ubuntu0.20.04.3) ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf ...
```

So my question I guess is what do I do about this? From trying to research this problem, I found a lot of posts saying don't go anywhere near killing processes and removing locks, how can I safely address this hang?

I can't see a link, but I'll mention it just in case it's relevant: I also appear to be having some issues with a mount of my network NAS, which was turned off a couple of days ago. Suspicious, I just tried to unmount it, but that command is just hanging.

EDIT: it seems that my missing mount *was* somehow the problem after all: I've just turned it back on and the upgrade process and lock finished immediately.

Comment: @user535733 I don't have that timestamp, but `unattended-upgrades-stamp` began at `2020-11-30 06:50`, and the only success timestamp, `update-success-stamp` occured at `2020-12-01 18:20`: (apologies for the formatting here!):

`$ ls -la /var/lib/apt/periodic/
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Nov 30 16:55 download-upgradeable-stamp`
`-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Nov 30 06:50 unattended-upgrades-stamp`
`-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Nov 30 16:55 update-stamp`
`-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Dec  1 18:20 update-success-stamp`
`-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Nov 30 06:50 upgrade-stamp`

Comment: What do you use mysql for? Do you have a backup in case the database is corrupted when you abort unattended-upgrades, release the lock, and reinstall that package? It shouldn't be corrupted by such activity...but stranger things have already happened.

Comment: I'm not actually sure what's using mysql on my system, but as it turns out, it seems that my missing mount _was_ somehow the problem after all: I've just turned it back on and the upgrade process and lock finished immediately.